# Prolog indirect relationship

Tags: prolog

I'm just start learning Prolog and facing a wired problem:

Suppose I have people waiting in two lines:

```
left(a,b).
left(c,i).
left(i,j).
right(k,j).
```

which represents lines like these:

```
line1:a,b  line2: c,i,j,k.
```

What I want is to see if any of these people are in same line. What I've wrote is following rules:

```
nextto(X,Y):- left(X,Y);left(Y,X);right(X,Y);right(Y,X).
sameline(X,Y):- nextto(X,Y).
sameline(X,Y):- nextto(X,Z),sameline(Z,Y).
```

I convert "`left/right`" into "`nextto`" relationship between people.
And the code works fine when two peoples are actually in same lines. But if I try:

```
?- sameline(a,c)
```

Where "a" and "c" are not in same line. The program goes into infinite loop until runs out of local stack. I assume it keeps trying to find variable "Z" between "X" and "Y" and if not found, the program will just create another "Z" to keep searching. I've seen the typical ancestor example using recursive call:

```
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z),ancestor(Z,Y).
```

which makes sense. But how is my code different from the ancestor example? Apparently `nextto(a,j)` will return false, but why the loop won't stop?

It's my second day of learning Prolog, so advanced use of Prolog might not help :(.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect for: `sameline(c,X) `, e.g what values of X makes it succeed??

Comment: From my code, `sameline(c,i) sameline(c,j) sameline(c,k)` will all return true since they are in same line.

Comment: Would the answer be the same if was `right(k,j)` ??  Then we would have `c ->i -> j and k->j` would these be two lines or k is considered in the line c,i,j??

Comment: I suppose you mean `right(j,k)`? This will cause error to the program. But the question here I don't need to consider this situation. Assume all the conditions are well ordered.

Comment: Yes I meant `right(j,k)`, `Assume all the conditions are well ordered` you mean that the lines will be clear (e.g we will not have examples like c ->i -> j and k->j) ??

Comment: Yea. We will only have conditions like `left(a,b), right(c,b):a->b->c.` We can also have `left(a,b),left(c,b)`,then `left/right(a,c)`. But we won't have `left(a,b), left(c,b)` with non-deterministic relationship between a and c.

Comment: One more: if I understand you right then in: `left(a,b),left(c,b),then left(a,c)` we will consider as two lines ,a->b and a->c->b??

Comment: This should be one line with three peoples: a->c->b. The question I have has two lines which are: 1. a->b 2.c->i->j->k. Sorry my explanation is not clear enough:(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trace:

```
?- sameline(a,c).
```

you will see that it falls into cycle `a <-> b` due to:

```
nextto(X,Y):- left(X,Y);left(Y,X);right(X,Y);right(Y,X).
```

In the rule above you let `next(a,b)` and `next(b,a)` to succeed but you need only one to succeed in order not to fall into cycle:

In trace you can see:

```
Redo: (8) sameline(a, c) ? creep    %OK trying to succeed sameline(a,c)
   Call: (9) nextto(a, _884) ? creep
```

The above continues with:

```
Call: (10) left(a, _884) ? creep
   Exit: (10) left(a, b) ? creep     %Only b succeeds left(a,_)
   Exit: (9) nextto(a, b) ? creep
   Call: (9) sameline(b, c) ? creep  %OK trying to succeed recursively
```

sameline(b,c).

But this ends up calling:

```
Redo: (9) sameline(b, c) ? creep
   Call: (10) nextto(b, _884) ? creep
   Call: (11) left(b, _884) ? creep
   Fail: (11) left(b, _884) ? creep
   Redo: (10) nextto(b, _884) ? creep
   Call: (11) left(_882, b) ? creep
   Exit: (11) left(a, b) ? creep
   Exit: (10) nextto(b, a) ? creep
   Call: (10) sameline(a, c) ? creep   % Same thing we began due to cycle
```

In order to solve this issue if I understand right what you're trying to do, you should define:

```
nextto(X,Y):- left(X,Y);right(Y,X).
sameline(X,Y):- nextto(X,Y).
sameline(X,Y):- nextto(X,Z),sameline(Z,Y).
```

This definition of `nextto/2` forces to follow one path-line and not fall into cycle.

Examples:

```
?- sameline(c,X).
X = i ;
X = j ;
X = k ;
false.

?- sameline(c,i).
true ;
false.

?- sameline(a,c).
false.
```

---

### EDIT

If you want nextto/2 to handle cycles, one way solving it is keeping a list of what you've visited:

```
sameline(X,Y):- sameline(X,Y,[X]).

nextto(X,Y):- left(X,Y);left(Y,X);right(X,Y);right(Y,X).
sameline(X,Y,_):- nextto(X,Y).
sameline(X,Y,L):- nextto(X,Z),\+member(Z,L),sameline(Z,Y,[Z|L]).
```

Comment: I understand what are you saying. But the issue here is that not only `sameline(c,i)` but also `sameline(i,c)` should also return true. That's why I have `nextto(X,Y):- left(X,Y);left(Y,X);right(X,Y);right(Y,X).` all these conditions for two adjacent people. But as you said, it falls into a<->b.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! Can you explain a little bit how this works? I haven't seen `\+member(Z,L),sameline(Z,Y,[Z|L]).` before.

Comment: The logic here is that you keep a list of what you have seen e.g `sameline(c,j).` will keep itially a list [c], then when visiting i (at this point i is not member of [c]) it will store it so the list will be [c,i] ,but this will prevent go back to c->i since now i is member of the list [c,i] so it prevents going back...until we reach j where it succeeds.

Comment: That makes sense!Thank you so much!

Comment: So what if I want `sameline(c,c)` to be true? I know I can add `sameline(X,Y):- X==Y.` But it is not entirely true since if I try `-? sameline(c,X)` the result will only be "i","j","k" without "c".

Comment: Just instead of `sameline(X,Y,[X]).` place `sameline(X,Y,[]).`